# How to parse json input in php (yii framework)

Tags: php, json, parsing, yii

I have JSON input as follows:

```
$json='{"PollQuestion":"Which is biggest country","Isactive":1,"options":[{"option":"abc"},{"option":"xyz"},{"option":"acssr"}]}'
$obj=json_encode($json);
```

So how to access options fields and individual option? I want to put these options in option table. Please help me in parsing this json input in php (Yii framework).

Comment: `CJSON::decode($json)` will return an array corresponding to that JSON string. `var_dump` it to see what it contains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$json='{"PollQuestion":"Which is biggest country","Isactive":1,"options":[{"option":"abc"},{"option":"xyz"},{"option":"acssr"}]}';

$decode = json_decode($json, true);
echo $decode['PollQuestion'];
```

Comment: Sir thanx for reply...i tried it but its giving me error as "trying to access property of non object"

Answer (score 3):

```
if you want to access as stdClass
$obj=json_decode($json);
print_r($obj->options);

if you want to access as hash array
$obj=json_decode($json,true);
print_r($obj['options']);
```

Comment: Sir thanx for reply...i tried it both ways but its giving me error as "trying to access property of non object"

Answer (score 2):

Yii has a helper class [CJSON](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON) it contains a method [CJSON::decode](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON#decode-detail) use it to decode the json string and use the decoded value as array not object.

Hope it helps